# Could someone help me with this function. When called to prints it should produce results like what's written in comments under the print statements

Tags: python, function

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    #code goes here

print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
# Should return the string "Name: Hemingway, Ernest"

print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
# Should return the string "Name: Madonna"

print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
# Should return the string "Name: Voltaire"

print(format_name("", ""))
# Should return an empty string
```

Comment: If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
  if len(first_name)==0:
    string="Name: "+last_name
    
  elif len(last_name)==0:
    string="Name: "+first_name
    
  else:
    string="Name: "+last_name+", "+first_name
```

Comment: Where's the `return`?

Comment: If you add `return string` at the end, then it doesn't work for `format_name("", "")` -> expected `''`, got `'Name: '`.

Comment: Answering bad or off-topic questions - like this one - attracts more bad or off-topic questions. Please don't answer this type of questions in the future.

Comment: To everyone I have offended I am very sorry for how I asked the question above. I am new to stack overflow and I am just 2 weeks in to learning python. Next time I will attempt to answer the question first then later ask for assistance. I will also look in to how to ask questions properly on stack overflow. Sorry for the inconvenience.